# AnyLogic - time plot export from resourcePool utilization

Tags: simulation, anylogic

In my model I simulate the work on an assembly line and for this I want to export a statistic of the ResourcePool into an Excel. This is how my time plot looks like:

[image]

In a way I would like to have this statistic automated in Excel as well. I guess for this I have to create a histogram dataset and choose as value the resourcePool.utilization(). In the best case, the x-axis is also still with time stamps of days.

But unfortunately I don't know exactly how to do that and how to get this dataset into Excel.  I know how to export individual data to an excel, but do I need to do the same here with this dataset? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

First, use a cyclic event to write the data into a database table (more flexible than using a dataset): https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/querying.html#insert

Next, let AnyLogic write the database results into your Excel file as described here: https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/export-excel.html#exporting-data-to-ms-excel-workbook

Check some example models as well, there are several that do this stuff